# Dapper.Rainbow column name is not escaped with '[]' for SQL Server

Tags: .net-8.0, dapper-rainbow

I want to try using `Dapper.Rainbow` mainly to have the ability to use Snapshotter and generate effective updates.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    // ...
    public int AK { get; set; }
    public int OR { get; set; } //issue is here
    // ...
}
```

My domain has many two-letter named fields, one of them is `OR`.
When it comes to insert through Dapper.Rainbow `Table` in `Database` class, the generated SQL looks like this

```
INSERT INTO MyEntity (.., AK, OR, ...) 
VALUES (...) --SQL syntax is incorrect here, reserved keyword `OR` is used
```

Is there a way to force using `[]` so it would be?

```
INSERT INTO MyEntity (.., [AK], [OR], ...) 
VALUES (...) --SQL syntax is fine
```

EF Core and Dapper.SimpleCRUD work fine for column `OR`, but I am looking something more lightweight than EF, but still with some sort of change tracking, so alternatives are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from right now this is not possible in `Dapper.Rainbow` , for creating the query it uses `PropertyInfo.Name` and when they are building the query they use just :

```
var sql = "set nocount on insert " + TableName + " (" + cols + ") values (" + colsParams + ") select cast(scope_identity() as int)";
```

You can check their [Gitub](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/main/Dapper.Rainbow/Database.Async.cs).

It is not bad idea though, you could create a PR for improvements yourself or maybe fork the repo and create your own version of the package.